# Can not load Skia.Package.FMX270.bpl?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, skia

Delphi 10.4 / Windows 10

I update Ski4Delphi-3.4.0 to Skia4Delphi-5.0.0 by GitIt Package Manager.
While reopening Delphi 10.4, it shows the Error :
Can't load package C:\Users\mitch\OneDrive\document\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\Skia4Delphi-5.0.0\Library\RAD Studio 10.4 Sydney\Win32\Release\Bpl
Access violation at address 0000000 in module 'bds.exe'. Read of address...................
as an Error picture was shown.
[image]

I do check the Skia.Package.FMX270.bpl is there as the file picture shows.
[image]

So, What is the reason let Delphi 10.4 IDE did not find the Skia.Pack.FMX270.Bpl and raise Error?

Comment: Check the Library Path in Delphi settings. Might be pointing to the wrong (old) version?